# Kafka Streams Standalone Spring Boot App Fails to connect to Kafka Brokers with Error Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 0

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams Standalone Spring Boot app fails to connect / disconnects from my kafka brokers and I cant seem to understand why. The kafka streams application fails with the error described below.

Here is my config

application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ubuntu2204.homelan.com:30003
    metrics:
      recording:
        level: DEBUG
    properties:
      sasl:
        mechanism: PLAIN
      security:
        protocol: PLAINTEXT
    streams:
      applicationId: garage-users-streams-app
      replication-factor: 1
      configuration:
        default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
        default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
        commit.interval.ms: 1000
```

My Kubernetes config

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka-broker
  name: kafka-svc-internal
  namespace: quantal-dev
spec:
  ports:
    - name: kafka-broker-internal
      port: 9092
  selector:
    app: kafka-broker

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka-broker
  name: kafka-broker
  namespace: quantal-dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka-broker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka-broker
    spec:
      hostname: kafka-broker
      containers:
      - name: kafka-broker
        env:
          - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
            value: "1"
          - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
            value: zookeeper-svc.quantal-dev:2181
          - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
            value: EXTERNAL://:30003,INTERNAL://:9092
          - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
            value: "EXTERNAL://ubuntu2204.homelan.com:30003,INTERNAL://kafka-svc-internal.quantal-dev:9092"
          - name: KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
            value: "EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
          - name: KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME
            value: "INTERNAL"
          - name: KAFKA_LOG_DIRS
            value: "/var/lib/kafka/data"
          - name: KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR
            value: "1"
          - name: KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS
            value: "car-garage-users:2:1,car-garage-vehicles:2:1"
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-svc
  name: zookeeper-svc
  namespace: quantal-dev
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: zookeeper-port
      port: 2181
      nodePort: 30181
      targetPort: 2181
  selector:
    app: zookeeper

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: zookeeper
  name: zookeeper
  namespace: quantal-dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.3
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: zookeeper
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
          env:
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT
              value: "2181"
            - name: ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME
              value: "2000"
```

Here is my Topology

```java
import com.quantal.garageusers.config.KafkaProducerProps;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class GarageUsersKakfaStreams {


    @Autowired
    public void buildUsersTopology(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder, KafkaProducerProps producerProps){

        KStream<String, String> userStream = streamsBuilder.stream(producerProps.getOutputTopic(), 
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        KTable<String, String> usersStore = userStream
                .mapValues( (value) -> value)
                .peek((key, value) -> System.out.println("User Record Key: "+ key + " record -> " + value))
                .toTable(Materialized.as("usersStore"));

    }
}
```

Here is the Error log

```
2023-04-18T19:55:05.362+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-StreamThread-1-producer] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
2023-04-18T19:55:05.372+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.4.0
2023-04-18T19:55:05.372+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 2e1947d240607d53
2023-04-18T19:55:05.372+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1681844105372
2023-04-18T19:55:05.376+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-StreamThread-1] Creating consumer client
2023-04-18T19:55:05.378+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = false
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [ubuntu2204.homelan.com:30003]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-StreamThread-1-consumer
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = garage-users-streams-app
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = false
    internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 1000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism = PLAIN
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 45000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

2023-04-18T19:55:05.387+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.k.s.p.i.a.AssignorConfiguration      : stream-thread [garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-StreamThread-1-consumer] Cooperative rebalancing protocol is enabled now
2023-04-18T19:55:05.399+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.4.0
2023-04-18T19:55:05.399+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 2e1947d240607d53
2023-04-18T19:55:05.399+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1681844105399
2023-04-18T19:55:05.404+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514] State transition from CREATED to REBALANCING
2023-04-18T19:55:05.405+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514] Started 1 stream threads
2023-04-18T19:55:05.405+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-StreamThread-1] Starting
2023-04-18T19:55:05.405+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-StreamThread-1] State transition from CREATED to STARTING
2023-04-18T19:55:05.405+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=garage-users-streams-app] Subscribed to topic(s): car-garage-users
2023-04-18T19:55:05.435+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [  restartedMain] c.q.garageusers.GarageUsersApplication   : Started GarageUsersApplication in 3.684 seconds (process running for 4.265)
2023-04-18T19:55:05.509+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [9058c4514-admin] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-admin] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-04-18T19:55:05.509+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [read-1-producer] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-StreamThread-1-producer] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-04-18T19:55:05.510+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=garage-users-streams-app] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-04-18T19:55:05.510+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [9058c4514-admin] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-admin] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 0 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 169ms, elapsed time since send: 169ms, request timeout: 3600000ms)
2023-04-18T19:55:05.510+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=garage-users-streams-app] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 1 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 10ms, elapsed time since send: 10ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2023-04-18T19:55:05.511+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [read-1-producer] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-StreamThread-1-producer] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 0 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 14ms, elapsed time since send: 14ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2023-04-18T19:55:05.511+01:00  WARN 87212 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=garage-users-streams-app] Bootstrap broker ubuntu2204.homelan.com:30003 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-04-18T19:55:05.511+01:00  WARN 87212 --- [read-1-producer] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-StreamThread-1-producer] Bootstrap broker ubuntu2204.homelan.com:30003 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-04-18T19:55:05.513+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [garage-users-streams-app-c03638b4-e7da-4039-b5f2-2369058c4514-StreamThread-1] Processed 0 total records, ran 0 punctuators, and committed 0 total tasks since the last update
2023-04-18T19:55:05.530+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [on(7)-127.0.0.1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-04-18T19:55:05.531+01:00  INFO 87212 --- [on(7)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Other clients can connect and consume and produce to the kafka cluster but the kafka streams application fails